# http.post not working in Angular 5

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing an app in Angular 5.

`http.get` service is working fine here but getting problem in `http.post`.

Below is my code:

```
GetEmployee() {
    //Data needs to be grouped in an object array as payload
    var payload = { "StaffCode": this.employeeCode };
    this.showLoader = true;
    this.http.post<StaffInfo>(this.baseURL + 'api/StaffDetail/GetEmployee', JSON.stringify(payload)).subscribe(result => {
        this.Staff = result;
        this.showLoader = false;
    }, error => console.error(error));
}
```

And API in .net core:

```
 [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public Employee GetEmployee(string StaffCode)
    {
        return util.GetEmployee(StaffCode);
    }
```

I am calling it on button click

```
<button type="button" (click)="GetEmployee()" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Get Detail</button>
```

but in my API it is null.

[image]

Am I calling post API in the wrong way?

One more thing, if I add `[FromBody]` before parameter signature than it does not even hit the API.

Comment: Typically, if the idea of that endpoint is to get an employee, you'd be better off using an HTTP GET request, and passing the `StaffCode` via the URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Client is sending a complex object model but action expects simple string.

Create model to match payload from client.

```
public class GetEmployeeModel {
    public string StaffCode { get; set; }
}
```

update action to expect payload in the body of the post.

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public Employee GetEmployee([Frombody]GetEmployeeModel model) {
    return util.GetEmployee(model.StaffCode);
}
```

Also ensure that the payload is constructed correctly on the client and sent with the correct content type

```
var payload = { StaffCode: this.employeeCode };
var json = JSON.stringify(payload);
var url = this.baseURL + 'api/StaffDetail/GetEmployee';
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })
};
this.http.post<StaffInfo>(url, json, httpOptions).subscribe(result => {
    this.Staff = result;
    this.showLoader = false;
}, error => console.error(error));
```

Now ideally, given the name of the action and the expected functionality, you would be better off refactoring the action to a HTTP GET request passing  the code in the route

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{StaffCode}")]
public Employee GetEmployee(string StaffCode)
{
    return util.GetEmployee(StaffCode);
}
```

And updating the client accordingly to make the request to

```
var url = this.baseURL + 'api/StaffDetail/GetEmployee/' + this.employeeCode;
this.http.get<StaffInfo>(url).subscribe(result => {
    this.Staff = result;
    this.showLoader = false;
}, error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: Thanks , I will try , but if I want to post a single string than how can I do ?

Comment: @Jack Use a simple object. you will post `JSON.stringify(this.employeeCode)` and keep the action parameter as string.

Comment: Your suggestion to use it as get with [HttpGet("[action]/{StaffCode}")] in api works , but in httppost JSON.stringify(this.employeeCode) does not work , still null

Comment: Don't forget the from body attribute

Comment: If I add [FromBody] than it say "the server responded with a status of 415 ()"

Comment: @Jack 415 means you are not sending the data with the correct content type header. check update

Comment: You must be provide content type into header